# After installing jenkins with tomcat manage jenkins is not showing

Tags: jenkins, tomcat7

I am new to jenkins I know how to run build on jenkins from remote .When I was trying to configure in my local I followed the steps as below

```
1) Downloaded  apache-tomcat-7.0.62
2) Downloaded jenkins.war [Jenkins ver. 1.651.2]
3) Copied jenkins.war and placed inside tomcat/webapps
4) Started the server 
5) After starting it deployed jenkins folder inside the webapps
6) Pointed the JENKINS_HOME env varibale to this folder.
```

I am able to see the dashboard on my borwser after the starting the server

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/jenkins/

But I am not getting any options like **Manage Jenkins** to customize anything.
Attached the screen shot for your reference.I tried with admin admin credentials but it didn't worked .What is the default credentials for this?.
and if any plugins I am missing please let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem today. It seems that you deleted, or it was not created - JENKINS_HOME folder, it should be placed in `user\.jenkins`.
At first check it - if there is really none, run the following command in folder with your `jenkins.war`, but **stop tomcat** first:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

After executing this command, go to http://localhost:8080 , it should run jenkins now not as tomcat part. Now you can create first admin user by follow instuctions.
When user was created, stop jenkins and run tomcat again, you will be able to login with created admin user in your tomcat/jenkins.